# Is there an alternative to Netcut in Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, software-recommendation

Is there any netcut software for ubuntu? I really need it since my LAN is being spoofed by some neighbors.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  Please add more detail to your post so that others can understand and answer it.  What is "netcut"?  What does "my LAN is keep on spoofing by my neighbor." mean?  Is your neighbor spoofing your wireless network, or maybe breaking into it?  Please elaborate.

Comment: All the info needed is there ;-) http://alternativeto.net/software/netcut/

Answer (score 5):

> [Tuxcut](https://github.com/a-atalla/tuxcut)

[image]

> Features

- Scan your local network for live hosts and list them with MAC addresses .
- Protect your linux box from any ARP attacks (like netcut) .
- Change the MAC address for your network adapter .
- you make arpspoof attack for any host connected in your local network.

> Installation

- It is not in USC but the website does have a [debian installer](https://github.com/a-atalla/tuxcut/releases/download/6.1/tuxcut_6.1_amd64.deb).

Comment: Not avaliable anymore...

Comment: yes it is @JoshuaSalazar

Comment: This package appears to no longer be working on Ubuntu.  If you believe this statement to be wrong, please comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73822929